# one jbutton doing different actions when clicked again

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton

I need the same `JButton` to perform a different actions once it's clicked again. Like the first time I click the button, a text will appear in the first row of my `JTextField`, then the second time I click it, a text will appear in the second row if text field. How should I do it?

Here is my code BTW:

```
private void addActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    String items1 =(String)list.getSelectedItem();
    String qty1 = qty.getText();
    String price1 = price.getText();


    int qty2 = Integer.parseInt(qty1);
    int price2 = Integer.parseInt(price1);

    if(evt.getSource() == add){
        order1.setText(Integer.toString(qty2));
        order2.setText(Integer.toString(price2));
        order3.setText(items1);
    }
```

I literally have no idea what to do next.

Here is the pic for the design GUI: http://prntscr.com/pfh96z

Answer (score 1):

Take a Boolean `isClickedOnce` and change its state upon clicking on your button

```
private Boolean isClickedOnce = false;
//..

private void addActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
    if(!isClickedOnce) {
        //first click
        //..
    } else {
        //second click
        //..
    }
    isClickedOnce = !isClickedOnce;
}
```

Note: it'll consider every odd number click as first click and every even number of click as second click. it will toggle through your first and second row.

If your case is different lets say you have n number of rows, above procedure won't work and you might wanna do something similar with a list.